# sACN communication from ETC ION to Beckhoff PLC controller - readout values are weird

Tags: structured-text

I am trying to read out sACN values ​​from an ETC ION Light desk using the Beckhoff PLC. I have successfully connected to universe 12 and can read out values ​​in the individual byte spaces. But all bytes that are connected to a lamp or similar are occasionally overwritten with the value 100 and then back to their original value. I can't figure out why it keeps receiving these values. Anyone familiar with ETC ION and Beckhoff sACN?

DMR is turned off, so its not the current problem, I quess :-/